# Connection refused on port 80 redirect to file

Tags: php, forms, error-handling, edit

I got a question: 
I got a webservice (table) indeed I can add remove and edit some records with php. 
Behind each button there is a PHP file, like edit.php, delete.php and so one. 
If I want to edit a record I get the following message displayed on my browser:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - localhost refused the connection

**EDIT.php:**

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    include'connect.php';

?>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pw","db");
    $first=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first']);
    $last=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last']);
    $phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);
    $age=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);
    $gender=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']);
    $blood=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['blood']);
    $occupation=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['occupation']);
    $qualification=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['qualification']);
    $address=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
    $city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);

    if(!empty($_FILES['image']))
    {
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $image = time().'.'.$ext;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], 'images/'.$image);
        //echo $image;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Image Is Empty";
    }

    $query1=mysqli_query($con, "insert into register values('','$first','$last','$phone','$age','$gender','$blood','$occupation','$qualification','$address','$image','$city')");
    //echo "insert into addd values('','$name','$age')";
    if($query1)
    {
        header("Location:http://localhost/dash/blood.php");
        ob_end_flush();
        die();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>//HTML//
```

The problem will be executed on this line:

```
 if($query1)
 {
     header("Location:http://localhost/dash/blood.php");
```

***What I did*** 
I changed localhost to the Server IP and it did not worked. 
Even if I removed dash and just added blood.php it did not worked equal same error.

**CMD:** 
Later on I executed the following command on cmd: 
**Result:**

```
  TCP    192.168.1.107:56487    93.184.220.29:80       WAIT         0
  TCP    192.168.1.107:56494    193.247.41.48:80       WAIT         0
  TCP    192.168.1.107:56512    185.73.44.35:80        SYN_SENT    6448
```

Are these connections the cause for my displayed error notification? 
And if so, do I have to close these connections?

Comment: If the HTML and the PHP files are on the same server, just do: `header("Location: /dash/blood.php");`. No need to include the hostname.

Comment: I'm also curious about why you're using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flus()` in that script. Doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Hey @MagnusEriksson <br>
Cool thank you very much Sir.
Its just a secure thing :D

Comment: How would `ob_start()` help you with security in this context?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ok Secure was the wrong word. I had a lot of problems with sessions and I read that it can never be wrong to add ob_start and flush on a php file

Comment: Well, that's mostly if you're doing things in the wrong order. You usually don't need it. In this code, I actually just saw a reason why your script wouldn't work without it. You're outputting a bunch of new lines before you do the `header()`-redirect, which wouldn't work without ob_start(). (since headers needs to be sent before any output at all). If it works, go for it! :-) I was just curious.

Comment: Hey cool! Thanks alot Magnus ;-)! @MagnusEriksson